# Scrollable, Clickable text in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, text, sdk, clickable

I'd like to make a text based app with clickable text in a scrollable screen. Can't seem to do it with TextView.

Let me explain: you open the app and there is a long paragraph. You scroll down and click on the word hammer (which is probably colored or bolded) and a small pop up window appears with a definition of hammer. How is this possible?

If you'd like to see an example, here is a youtube vid of somewhat similar functions in a bible app (though they don't use a pop up box): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNCgePlBamQ

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UIWebView and HTML

and this: [iOS Clickable Words (UILabel or UIbutton's)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078789/ios-clickable-words-uilabel-or-uibuttons) was asked suspiciously recently